# Node crypto.randomBytes return token from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, token, node-crypto

**Summary**

I have a function where I use crypto.randomBytes to generate a token and I'm having trouble returning the token from the function.  I want to return token from createResetToken.  My function is below and I've tried many different things but they aren't working.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Code**

```
function createResetToken() {
  crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
    const token = buf.toString("hex");
    console.log("token inside inside", token);
    return token;
  });

}
```

Comment: do you want return token from createResetToken call?

Comment: Yes!  You got it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way of doing this is using sync way of [randomBytes()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_randombytes_size_callback), you can make it by just not providing a callback function:

```
function createResetToken() {
  return crypto.randomBytes(20).toString("hex");
}
```

By docs:

> If a callback function is provided, the bytes are generated
>   asynchronously and the callback function is invoked with two
>   arguments: err and buf. If an error occurs, err will be an Error
>   object; otherwise it is null. The buf argument is a Buffer containing
>   the generated bytes.
>
> ...
>
> If the callback function is not provided, the random bytes are
>   generated synchronously and returned as a Buffer. An error will be
>   thrown if there is a problem generating the bytes.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks for your help, especially so quickly!  I'll accept your answer once it allows me to in 4 minutes